# Android create table error

Tags: android, sql

When I try to create the a table the very first time, I always get this error message:

> sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed
>   on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

My code looks like this:

// debuggin identifier
    private static final String TAG = DatabaseOpenHandler.class.getSimpleName();

```
// name and verison of the database
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OpenConfApp";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// name and attributes of the table notes
public static final String TABLE_NAME_NOTES = "notes";
public static final String _NOTE_ID = "_noteId";
public static final String NOTE_CONFERENCE = "conferenceId";
public static final String NOTE_DATE = "dateInMillis";
public static final String NOTE_TEXT = "noteText";

// create table notes
public static final String TABLE_NOTES_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_NAME_NOTES + " (" + _NOTE_ID
        + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOTE_CONFERENCE
        + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_DATE + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_TEXT
        + " INTEGER);";

// drop table notes
public static final String TABLE_NOTES_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST "
        + TABLE_NAME_NOTES;

public DatabaseOpenHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
    db.execSQL(TABLE_NOTES_CREATE);
}
```

Sorry, I'm new to Android programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct Just you missed a space before your first integer statement.Write this:

```
public static final String TABLE_NOTES_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_NAME_NOTES + " (" + _NOTE_ID
    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOTE_CONFERENCE
    + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_DATE + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_TEXT
    + " INTEGER);";
```

Comment: why are you repeating me? -_-

Comment: @sebbl.sche Scandal. I was the first to give this answer.

Comment: sry dear but I really didnot see your answer that you have posted as my net was slow. really sry.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOTE_CONFERENCE
```

you missed a blank space over there...

```
+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOTE_CONFERENCE
```

Answer (score 0):

AUTOINCREMENT is not needed for integer primary key, it's semantics already contains in "primary key", see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem due to typing error
there is no space between

NOTE_ID and INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

```
public static final String TABLE_NOTES_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_NAME_NOTES + " (" + _NOTE_ID
        + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOTE_CONFERENCE
        + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_DATE + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_TEXT
        + " INTEGER);";
```

you should give the space between them

```
public static final String TABLE_NOTES_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_NAME_NOTES + " (" + _NOTE_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOTE_CONFERENCE
        + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_DATE + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_TEXT
        + " INTEGER);";
```